# Measuring a quantum state for entanglement

Tags: quantum-entanglement, quantum-measurements

I am new to the concept of quantum entanglement and measurement. The scarce knowledge about them that I have is

1. As soon as you measure, the system collapses into one of the vectors of the eigenbasis in which you measured.
2. To actually identify whether a quantum state is entangled or not you need to measure the system many times and judge based on the correlated or anticorrelated of their states (focusing on Bell states).

My question is suppose $A$ and $B$ have shared a Bell state but they don't know which one. They both decide to measure their particle in the computational basis $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$.  How does say $B$ get to know what was the Bell pair shared if he keeps on measuring both particles one after the another because as soon as he measures the system the original should be lost, how does he build the original state again and start the measuring process again.

Is there something additional that has to be added to the hypothesis before we measure the particles and try to find out the Bell state. Pardon me for my lack of knowledge on this concept as I have recently began studying quantum entanglement and their application to secret sharing.

Comment: *"how does he build the original state again"* He can't. He has to measure another particle.

Comment: okay, but even if he measures how can he continuously do this

Comment: "To actually identify whether a quantum state is entangled or not you need to measure the system many times" .. No, this is false. You prepare many identical copies and do one measurement on each copy. Then check the statistics to see if you violated a Bell like inequality

Comment: okay so i need to make multiple copies